# solving diophantine equations using congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, linear-diophantine-equations

So, a question in Elementary Number Theory by David M. Burton:

```
    Problems 4.4 
    2(a) Using congruences, solve the diophantine equation 4x + 51y = 9
```

*Hint: $4x \equiv 9(mod \ 51) $ gives $ x = 15 +51t$, whereas $ \ 51y \equiv 9 (mod \ 4)$ gives $y = 3+4s $. Find the relation between $s$ and $t$*

From this hint, I substitute $ x = 15 +51t$ and $y = 3+4s$ in the given equation $4x + 51y = 9$ to get the relation $s = -t-1$ and using which I can get the solutions $ x = 15 + 51t, \ y =-1-4t$

But we know that the solutions of $ax \equiv b (mod \ n)$ is equivatent to the solutions of the diophantine equation $ax -ny = b$,

so, solutions of $4x \equiv 9(mod \ 51) $ is equivalent to solutions of the equation $4x-51y=9$

whereas, solutions of $51y \equiv 9(mod \ 4) $ is equivalent to solutions of the equation $-4x+51y=9$

Now, my question is:

as, the above equations $4x-51y=9$ and $-4x+51y=9$ are different, then what is the point of substituting $ x = 15 +51t$ (solution of $4x-51y=9$) and $y = 3+4s $ (solution of $-4x+51y=9$) in the given equation $4x+51y=9$ to find a relation between $t$ and $s$ ? Isn't it absurd as $ x = 15 +51t$ and $y = 3+4s $ are solutions of two different equations? Can anyone please explain this?

PS: I did it like this $4x \equiv 9(mod \ 51) $ gives $ x = 15 +51t$ and by substituting it in $4x+51y=9$ we get $y=-1-4t$

Comment: Whenever you have a question, make sure it wasn't already asked here before. [This should have what you are looking for.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725670/how-can-i-solve-4x-51y-9-using-congruences?rq=1) Also, being more specific on your question title will help you in getting an answer more quickly. Diophantine equations can range from a simple exercise (as it's the case here) to absurdly hard, unsolved problems.

Comment: @GuilhermeMartins It's the same question, but none of the answers there make any attempt at all to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the argument outlined in equational logic (vs. less precise English language). No use is made of $\,4x-51y = 9.\,$ The elimination steps use $E_z\!:\,z = c,\, az = b\iff z=c,\, ac = b,\,$ familiar as an elementary row operation in Gaussian elimination (triangularization) in linear algebra.

$$\begin{align}
 4x+51y\, =\, 9\, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ & \\[.2em]
\iff\ 4x+51y\, =\, 9\, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \&\ \ &x = 15+51t\ \ \&\ \ y = 3+4s\\[.2em]
\iff  204(t+s) = -204\ \ \&\ \ &x = 15+51t\ \ \&\ \ y = 3+4s,\ \ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ E_x,\,E_y\\[.2em]
\iff\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   t+s = -1\ \ \ \ \ \ \&\ \ &x = 15+51t\ \ \&\ \ y = 3+4s,\ \ \ \ {\rm by\ cancel}\ 204\\[.2em]
\iff  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \phantom{t+s = -1\ \&}\ &x = 15+51t\ \ \&\ \ y = -1-4t,\ \ {\rm by}\ \ E_s \ 
\end{align}$$

What you did - solve one congruence first, then substitute - is generally simpler and the more common way to proceed, i.e. in equational language as above

$$\begin{align}
 4x+51y\, =\, 9\, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  & \\[.2em]
\iff\ 4x+51y\, =\, 9\, \ \ \ \ \ \ \&\ \ &x = 15+51t\\[.2em]
\iff    51y = -51\!-\!204t\ \ \&\ \   &x = 15+51t,\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ E_x\\[.2em]
\iff\ \ \  \ \:\!   y = -1-4t\ \ \ \ \ \ \&\ \ &x = 15+51t,\ \ \ {\rm by\ cancel}\ 51
\end{align}\qquad$$

**Remark**  $ $ If instead of the above (bidirectional) equivalences we use only *unidirectional* arrows $(\Rightarrow)$ then we obtain only *necessary* conditions on the solutions. Then to verify sufficiency we have to check that the candidate  solutions actually work (are not extraneous roots). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20unidirectional) for more on the insufficiency of unidirectional inferences.